# Get return value of an item clicked

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to figure out how to get a TObject (TLabel or TCard) as a returned value after a player has clicked on the object.

Goes like this

```
Player plays a spell //
Spell says hey i need a target //
spell calls get a target //
player selects a target //
target is returned to spell//
spell does xx with target//
```

Here is an example of code.

```
procedure TSpell.Spell;
var
secondTarget : Tobject;
begin
if true then
begin 
  secondTarget := GetSecondTarget();  //how??
     if SecondTarget.classname = TCard then 
         begin
             showmessage('you selected a TCard');
          end
     if SecondTarget.classname = TLabel then
          begin
              showmessage('you selected a label');
          end
end


GetSecondTarget() : TObject;
begin
   showmessage('Select a Target');
   //wait for user to click something
   //return the TObject to TSpell.spell
end;
```

I have no idea on how to do the GetSecondTarget... how to wait for user to click on something then return it to TSpell.Spell  Any help on how to do this?

Comment: The GUI is event driven. Have a global state variable to decide what to do when an object is clicked.

Comment: You can "switch" your application into some "spell target selection" mode from your `Spell` method. Then you can handle click events as usually, you just check if you're in normal or that special mode and do something according to this.

Comment: Please do not show fake code that did not compile `SecondTarget.classname = TLabel`

Comment: its was an example i never said it was compiled code..

Answer (score 1):

Windows GUI programs are event driven. You should not contemplate calling a function on the main thread that will block until an event happens.

What's more, your call to `ShowMessage` results in a modal dialog. And modal dialogs disable their owning windows which means that the user is not able to click on the object that you are hoping they will click on. If you wish to show a form with an instruction, then at the very least it needs to be a modeless dialog.

The bottom line here is that you need to adapt your ideas to the concepts of event-driven programming. When the user clicks on an object, an `OnClick` event will be raised. Attach a handler to that event and respond to it when that handler executes. If you need to behave differently to the `OnClick` event at different times, you'll need to maintain some state in your program to determine that behaviour switching.

Comment: yes, so `GetSecondTarget` sets a var `STarget := true` Now during the onclick it will check if STarget is true. If it is true, How do i get that value back to `TSpell.spell`

Comment: You have to redesign that. Remember that your code is executing in the same thread of execution as the GUI. You cannot block the GUI thread. You handle clicks when they happen. Once you have found two successive clicks that meet your needs, then you can do your spell. They key to make this work is to hold state that can be used to make the event handlers behave differently at different stages of the user's navigation through your GUI.

Comment: how to redesign is the issue in real code i have a case statement for "CType" , wich is a value in the db.. if the value is target, then it means user needs to select a target.   i guess i can use the case statement for "target" to set a var = true... then on click ill just run a TSpell.TspellTarget() procedure..but seems wrong lol

Comment: @GlenMorse said: "_but seems wrong_" It may seem wrong for now, but once you get the hang of it, you'll learn that it's much better. Breaking your steps down into smaller chunks like `StartCastingSpell` and later `CastSpellAtTarget(...)` will make your code much more testable and maintainable in the long run.